# Copy previous row value to all next rows in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have requirement to copy previous rows values to next all rows in sql server.

With LAG function, I can achieve this one only for next row. but I have to copy more than rows.

Here is sample example :

[image: Attaching Image for expected result]

Comment: please post sample example as text

Comment: What is the criteria for ordering the data? You need to show the criteria in order for us to be able to know which are the `previous` rows. It will be enough to show the `T-SQL` statement you use.

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.CustID,
    t2.ID,
    t2.CustID,
    t2.Flag,
    COALESCE(
        t2.Flag,
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 l.Flag 
            FROM TBL2 l
            WHERE l.CustID = t1.CustID AND l.ID < t1.ID
            ORDER BY l.ID desc
        )) as 'Final'
FROM
    TBL1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL2 t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.CustID = t1.CustID
ORDER BY
    t1.CustID,
    t1.ID desc
```

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL1 (ID int, CustID int)
GO

CREATE TABLE TBL2 (ID int, CustID int, Flag bit)
GO

INSERT INTO TBL1 (ID, CustID)
SELECT 1, 11 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 12 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 13 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 14 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 15 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 16 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 17 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 11 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 12 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 13 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 14 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 15 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 16 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 17 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 11 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 12 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 13 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 14 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 15 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 16 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 17 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 11 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 12 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 13 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 14 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 15 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 16 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 17

GO

INSERT INTO TBL2 (ID, CustID, Flag)
SELECT 1, 11, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 12, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 13, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 14, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 15, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 16, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 17, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 11, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 13, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 14, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 15, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 17, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 13, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 15, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 17, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 12, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 17, 0

GO
```

Comment: Isn't that essentially a copy of my answer?

Comment: Yes, I had attempted using `CROSS APPLY` and a `CTE` but wasn't successful with getting those to work. I posted what I had as it contains the creation and insertion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT *
      ,ISNULL(b.flag,(MAX(b.flag) OVER (PARTITION BY a.[custid] ORDER BY b.[id] DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)))
FROM @TBL1 A
LEFT JOIN @TBL2 B
    ON A.id = b.id
    AND A.custid = b.custid
ORDER BY a.[custid] ASC, a.[id] DESC
```

Here is the sample data:

```
DECLARE @TBL1 TABLE
(
    [id] TINYINT
   ,[custid] TINYINT
);

DECLARE @TBL2 TABLE
(
    [id] TINYINT
   ,[custid] TINYINT
   ,[flag] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @TBL1([id], [custid])
VALUES 
(1,11)
,(1,12)
,(1,13)
,(1,14)
,(1,15)
,(1,16)
,(1,17)
,(2,11)
,(2,12)
,(2,13)
,(2,14)
,(2,15)
,(2,16)
,(2,17)
,(3,11)
,(3,12)
,(3,13)
,(3,14)
,(3,15)
,(3,16)
,(3,17)
,(4,11)
,(4,12)
,(4,13)
,(4,14)
,(4,15)
,(4,16)
,(4,17);

INSERT INTO @TBL2 ([id], [custid], [flag])
VALUES (1,11,0)
,(1,12,1)
,(1,13,1)
,(1,14,0)
,(1,15,0)
,(1,16,0)
,(1,17,1)
,(2,11,1)
,(2,13,0)
,(2,14,1)
,(2,15,1)
,(2,17,0)
,(3,13,1)
,(3,15,0)
,(3,17,1)
,(4,12,0)
,(4,17,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` ,a `CASE EXPRESSION` and a correlated query :

```
SELECT t.id,t.custid,s.id,s.custid,
       COALESCE(s.flag,(SELECT TOP 1 ss.flag FROM tbl2 ss
                        WHERE ss.custid = t.custid and ss.id < t.id
                        ORDER BY ss.id DESC)) as flag
FROM Tbl1 t
LEFT JOIN tbl2 s
 ON(t.custid = s.custid and s.id = t.id)
```